# if_attribute on declarative authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, declarative-authorization

I have a many-to-many relationship like this:
A user has_many organizations through affiliations and vice-versa.

I'm using declarative organizations and I only want a user to edit a particular organization if he is affiliated and the affiliationtype attribute of affiliation is a particular value.

So affiliations has 3 columns , user_id, organization_id and affiliationtype_id

I can do:

```
o = Organization.find(:first)
o.affiliatons[0].user and get the user
```

now I wish to do this:

```
has_permission_on [:organizations], :to => :edit do
  if_attribute (...)
end
```

That if_attribute should see if the current user is the organization.affiliation[?].user and if the organization.affiliation[?].affiliationtype_id = "3"

I hope this is syntax issue ... I really need to get this working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can restrict the type of affiliation with **intersects_with(&block)** :

```
  has_permission_on [:organizations], :to => :edit do
    if_attribute :affiliations => intersects_with {
      user.affiliations.with_type_3
    }
  end
```

Why not create a named_scope to find affiliations whose affiliationtype_id = 3?

---

From [declarative_authorization documentation](http://www.tzi.org/~sbartsch/declarative_authorization/master/files/README_rdoc.html):

*To reduce redundancy in has_permission_on blocks, a rule may depend on permissions on associated objects:*

```
authorization do
  role :branch_admin do
    has_permission_on :branches, :to => :manage do
      if_attribute :managers => contains {user}
    end

    has_permission_on :employees, :to => :manage do
      if_permitted_to :manage, :branch
      # instead of
      #if_attribute :branch => {:managers => contains {user}}
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I can find the user and validate the match. But I need to find the user AND see if is affiliation has an affiliationtype of a certain id.
I can get is user_id, but how do i see for the affiliationtype of that user_id? I don't get it...

Comment: See my edit, I think this can help. There's only one or zero affiliation object that intersects with Organization.affiliations and user.affiliations.with_type_3 (named_scope suggestion).

Comment: almost...
this works on the console giving me just one value for the user:
v.affiliations.type_admin

but the 

      if_attribute :affiliations => intersects_with {
        user.affiliations.type_admin
      }

Never validates true

Comment: You added the named_scope to the Affiliation model? named_scope :type_admin, :conditions => {:affiliationtype_id => 3}

Comment: I've tried exactly the same thing but it hasn't worked for me... :/ 
Has the gem been updated at all?

Comment: I love it.  Thanks!  I have a habtm relationship and the contains{user} block works nicely.